# R memory importing SPSS

Tags: r, memory, spss

I am trying to load in R a dataset in a .sav (SPSS) format.

And I reached this error:

```
dataset <- read.spss("file.sav", to.data.frame = TRUE)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.7 Gb
```

I tried using the option *nrow = 100* but it's not define in the mentionned function

Comment: Can you try haven::read_sav() instead?

Comment: @Vlo tried right now and same problem. I'm investigating into the `ff` package...